# Save colab results

Tags: python-2.7

I am using google colab but I can not save the results directly from colab to my google drive or even in my computer. Can anybody give me a hand?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can save data to Google Drive by doing this :

```
import pickle
from google.colab import drive
from pathlib import Path

# this will mount your google drive in the server where your code is running
drive.mount('/content/gdrive', force_remount=True)
ROOT_DIR = "/content/gdrive/My Drive/"

obj = {'hello': 'world'}
filepath = Path(ROOT_DIR) / 'my_file.pkl'
pickle.dump(obj, open(filepath, 'wb'))
```

Answer (score 0):

After mounting your Google drive. You can do the following to save your work on the drive:
1 Click File.
2 Click Save File in Drive.